# document.getElementById("…").className = "…"; Not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, getelementbyid, classname

I created a business generator here: http://minespress.net/web_apps/business-cards/

I created a preview pane using `document.getElementById("…").className = "…";` which switches the background image onClick (of the thumbnail) and also moves around the text divs depending on the design of the business card. This works flawlessly in FF, Chrome and Safari. When I tried it in IE nothing happened onClick.

I should also mention that my thumbs are radio buttons that need to change the form action based whether or not they are checked. Once again works fine in other browsers besides IE. Is there some IE bug or am I just doing something completely wrong?

Here is an example of my code:

```
<input
    style="display:none"
    checked="checked"
    name="group1"
    id="2"
    value='http://minespress.net/web_apps/business-cards/img/twinkle-blue.jpg'
    type="radio"
    onclick="document.getElementById('card').className ='Default'; document.getElementById('compname').className ='', document.getElementById('slogan').className ='', document.getElementById('leftinfo').className ='', document.getElementById('rightinfo').className =''" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 8 does not support images as labels for input fields. This is why my radio buttons do not work. Now I just need to figure out how to work around this.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/using_images_as Thank god!

Answer (score 1):

Use setAttribute instead:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('card')
ele.setAttribute('class', 'Default');
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `setAttribute('class', 'Default')`?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: The `setAttribute` version of your fiddle does not work on IE 9.

Comment: This isn't working for me either. I'm thinking about trying to make the JS so it's not inline but am having trouble doing it. The class change on this site http://www.ezineasp.net/Samples/Javascript/Javascript-DOM/Change-CSS-Class-of-Div-Tag/Default.aspx does work in IE

Comment: I still can't get this to work in IE 8. Now the site that listed above doesn't work either. I am really at loss for what to do. Could somebody see if it works for them in IE 8?

Comment: [`.className` compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t00) and [`.setAttribute(...)` compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t1110).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing the `,`s to `;`s? IE might be pickier than the other browsers...

Change

`"document.getElementById('card').className ='Default'; document.getElementById('compname').className ='', document.getElementById('slogan').className ='', document.getElementById('leftinfo').className ='', document.getElementById('rightinfo').className =''"`

to

`"document.getElementById('card').className ='Default'; document.getElementById('compname').className =''; document.getElementById('slogan').className =''; document.getElementById('leftinfo').className =''; document.getElementById('rightinfo').className =''"`

and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. It has to be some small problem that I am not seeing or realize. Thank you for your response

Comment: I checked your site with IE 9. Besides the first two cards (you have a syntax error in `document.getElementById('card').setAttribute('class', 'Default')';`, the last `'` is obsolete), it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Are you able to try it in IE 8? I just can't get it to work in there. I am so frustrated.